# Notation for the union of a system of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

The [notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29#Notations) $\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}$ denotes the union of the range of a function, and as such, is used only if we are considering some function (*an indexed family*).

> The generalized associative law for unions can be stated like this:
>
> $$\bigcup_{a \in \bigcup S}F_{a}=\bigcup_{C \in S}\left(\bigcup_{a \in
>  C}F_{a}\right)$$

1. Does the first $\bigcup$ on the RHS gain a new meaning when used in
   a row as above? If not, what is the function whose union of the
   range it represents?
2. Concerning the second $\bigcup$, I guess we might assume that
        \begin{align} x \in \bigcup_{a \in C}F_{a} &\iff x \in \bigcup \text{ran }F, \quad F:C \to \{F_{a} \mid a \in C\}\\ &\iff \exists b
       \in \text{ran }F(x \in b)\\ & \iff \exists b(b \in \text{ran }F\land
       x \in b)\\ & \iff \exists b(\exists a \in C(aFb) \land x \in b)\\
       &\iff \exists b(\exists a (a \in C \land aFb) \land x \in b)\\
       \end{align}

   But, also in an intuitive way
        \begin{align} x \in \bigcup_{a \in C}F_{a} &\iff \exists a \in C(x\in F_{a})\\ & \iff\exists a (a \in C \land x \in F_{a})\\ &\iff
       \exists a(a \in C \land\exists b(aFb \land x \in b)) \end{align} Are
   these statements really equivalent?
3. I understand the idea of the generalized associative law for unions, but how can a precise
   definiton for $x \in \bigcup_{C \in S}(\bigcup_{a \in C}F_{a})$ be
   formulated?

Comment: The function you are looking for in (1) is $C\mapsto \bigcup_{a \in
 C}F_{a}$. Is that not formal enough for you?

Comment: We have $ \exists b(\exists a (a \in C \land aFb) \land x \in b)\iff \exists b(\exists a (a \in C \land aFb \land x \in b)) \iff \exists a(\exists b (a \in C \land aFb \land x \in b)) \iff \exists a(a \in C \land\exists b(aFb \land x \in b))$. Does this answer (2)?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Yes, it's formal enough. I didn't realise $C$ in $\bigcup_{a \in C}F_a$ was an index as $i$ is in $\bigcup_{i \in I}A_{i}$. The other comment answers (2).

Comment: Great, problem solved :)

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Not for the 3rd question yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
x\in \bigcup_{C\in S}\left(\bigcup_{a\in C}F_{a}\right)&\iff \exists C\in S\left(x\in \bigcup_{a\in C}F_{a}\right)\\
\\
\\
\\
&\iff \exists C\in S(\exists a\in C(x\in F_{a}))\\
\\
&\iff \exists C\in S(\exists a(a\in C\land x\in F_{a}))\\
\\
&\iff \exists C(C\in S\land \exists a(a\in C\land x\in F_{a}))\\
\\
&\iff \exists C(\exists a(C\in S\land a\in C\land x\in F_{a}))\\
\\
&\iff \exists a(\exists C(C\in S\land a\in C\land x\in F_{a}))\\
\\
\\
&\iff \exists a(\exists C(C\in S\land a\in C)\land x\in F_{a})\\
\\
&\iff \exists a(\exists C\in S(a\in C)\land x\in F_{a})\\
\\
&\iff \exists a(a\in  \bigcup S\land x\in F_{a})\\
\\
&\iff \exists a\in \bigcup S(x\in F_{a})\\
\\
&\iff x\in \bigcup_{a\in \bigcup S} F_{a}\\
\end{align}